# VB.NET Linq Left Join using Query Syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq, left-join, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types

I have a list of applications.  Each application may or may not have a support record associated with it.

The only way I can join is to take the App Title and see if its equal to the LookupValue of Support(Product).  But to get that property, i have to cast to a FieldLookupValue.  When there is no associated support record, that is where the null reference error gets thrown on `.MoveNext()` inside the Linq query.  Below is what currently works for apps that have associated support, but throws the error when they don't.

```
Dim q =
    From a In apps.AsEnumerable()
    Group Join s In support.AsEnumerable()
    On a("Title").ToString() Equals CType(s("Product"), FieldLookupValue).LookupValue 
    Into Group
    From ajs In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
    Select New With {
        .Name = a("Title"),
        .SupportEnd = IIf(ajs Is Nothing, Nothing, ajs("End"))
    }
```

Any way I could compare anonymous types in the On Statement?  I can't seem to get the syntax right on that, or maybe its not possible.  I feel that could fix the null reference error.  My unsuccessful attempt returned **Equals cannot compare type  with the value of type**

```
Dim q =
   From a In apps.AsEnumerable()
   Group Join s In support.AsEnumerable()
   On
   (New With {Key .AppName = a("Title").ToString()}) Equals
   (New With {Key .AppName = IIf(s Is Nothing, "nada", CType(s("Product"), FieldLookupValue).LookupValue)})
   Into Group
   From ajs In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
   Select New With {
      .Name = a("Title"),
      .SupportEnd = IIf(ajs("End") Is Nothing, Nothing, ajs("End"))
   }
```

Any ideas as to how to get this join to work using one of the two failed methods above would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I created a dummy default object based on a random selection from the support list (i chose index 0), I used that to compare to as shown.  Then just used the Let statement to have a boolean easily accessible when selecting.

```
Dim q =
    From a In apps.AsEnumerable()
    Group Join s In support.AsEnumerable()
    On a("Title").ToString() Equals CType(s("Product"), FieldLookupValue).LookupValue 
    Into Group
    From ajs In Group.DefaultIfEmpty(support(0))
    Let NoSupport As Boolean = IIf(ajs.Equals(support(0)), True, False)
    Select New With {
        .Name = a("Title"),
        .SupportEnd = IIf(NoSupport, "No Support", ajs("End"))
    }
```